# how to add a java package to my java library?

Tags: java, external

I have 1.6.0_22 version of Java installed on Mac OS X.  I was trying to write a file operation program and wanted to use `java.nio.file` package's 'Path' class but I can't find that package?  How can I add it to my project?

Answer (score 1):

[`Path`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) is only available in Java 1.7:

From the [JavaDocs](http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html):

> Since:
>   1.7